# Unique line in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm on Sqldeveloper/Oracle and I would like to regroup my three line in one line. It's posible ?
For exemple I have this :

[image]

with this code :

```
select DISTINCT PRO.CODPRO as SKU,PRO.MOTCLE AS PARENTPRODUCTSKU,DECODE(FAM.CODEFAM,' ',' ',FAM.LIBFAM) AS MarketNomLab1,DECODE(FAM.CODESFA,' ',' ',FAM.LIBFAM) AS MarketNomLab2,DECODE(FAM.CODESSF,' ',' ',FAM.LIBFAM) AS MarketNomLab3
FROM PRO 
  JOIN PRB ON PRO.CODPRO=PRB.CODPRO 
  JOIN FAM ON PRB.CODSOC=FAM.CODSOC 
WHERE fam.typtie='PRO' 
  AND (FAM.CODEFAM=PRO.FAMPRO OR FAM.CODESFA=PRO.SFAPRO OR FAM.CODESSF=PRO.SSFPRO);
```

and I would like this :

[image]

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    PRO.CODPRO as SKU,
    PRO.MOTCLE AS PARENTPRODUCTSKU,
    MAX(DECODE(FAM.CODEFAM,' ',' ',FAM.LIBFAM)) AS MarketNomLab1,
    MAX(DECODE(FAM.CODESFA,' ',' ',FAM.LIBFAM)) AS MarketNomLab2,
    MAX(DECODE(FAM.CODESSF,' ',' ',FAM.LIBFAM)) AS MarketNomLab3 
FROM PRO 
JOIN PRB ON PRO.CODPRO = PRB.CODPRO 
JOIN FAM ON PRB.CODSOC = FAM.CODSOC 
WHERE fam.typtie='PRO' AND (FAM.CODEFAM = PRO.FAMPRO OR FAM.CODESFA = PRO.SFAPRO OR FAM.CODESSF = PRO.SSFPRO)
GROUP BY PRO.CODPRO, PRO.MOTCLE
```

The structure of your query makes me suspect whether you might actually be looking for conditional aggregation. Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT 
    PRO.CODPRO as SKU,
    PRO.MOTCLE AS PARENTPRODUCTSKU,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FAM.CODEFAM = PRO.FAMPRO THEN FAM.LIBFAM END) AS MarketNomLab1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FAM.CODESFA = PRO.SFAPRO THEN FAM.LIBFAM END) AS MarketNomLab2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FAM.CODESSF = PRO.SSFPRO THEN FAM.LIBFAM END) AS MarketNomLab3 
FROM PRO 
JOIN PRB ON PRO.CODPRO = PRB.CODPRO 
JOIN FAM ON PRB.CODSOC = FAM.CODSOC 
WHERE fam.typtie='PRO' AND (FAM.CODEFAM = PRO.FAMPRO OR FAM.CODESFA = PRO.SFAPRO OR FAM.CODESSF = PRO.SSFPRO)
GROUP BY PRO.CODPRO, PRO.MOTCLE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for thank you very much !!!